# Pads on middle of the tracks on PCB

Tags: pcb-design, production-testing

I'm pretty new to PCB design stuff so please excuse my simple question.

What is the purpose of the pads I show in the pictures? It is sometimes used in the middle of the tracks and sometimes at the end.

[image: End of the track]
[image: Middle of the tracks]

Comment: Is it a Test point? What's on the other side? Maybe it's just a plugged via because it ends up under a component on the other side.

Comment: Actually, I don't know the design because these are the photos I found on the internet but, "test point" makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

These are test pads for in-circuit component testing during manufacturing. When manufacturing, It is important to detect issues as early in the process as possible. Each step of the manufacturing process adds more cost so detecting and fixing an error early saves on cost.

In this case, once all components are placed on the board they are tested for existence, correct value, and correct polarity. The PCB is designed with a test at every electrical node on one side of the board. After the components have been placed on the board, the board is placed on to a "bed of nails". As the board is pressed onto the nails, each nail makes electrical contact with a test pad.

The in-circuit test (ICT) begins testing for shorts and opens by connecting a pair of nails through relays to an ohmmeter and a measurement is made to determine if there is conductivity between the two electrical nodes of the PCB or not. Every combination of nail pairs is measured and the results compared to the expected shorts/open pattern. Any deviation from the expected indicates that the board has an unexpected short or open.

The next step of ICT is to test the components. For every component, the nails for the electrical nodes of that component are connected through relays to a measuring device. Resistors are tested by applying a voltage across the component and measuring the resulting current. Diodes may be tested by applying a voltage at each polarity and measuring the resulting current and voltage drop. Capacitors and inductors are tested for the appropriate impedance at a certain frequency. In this manner all kinds of components can be verified assembled correctly.

You may be wondering now one can test components in-circuit when there are multiple paths for current to flow other than through the component under test. This is accomplished through "guarding". Electrical nodes at the opposite end of components connected to the component under test are forced to the same voltage as the node connected at the component under test. When the voltage at each end of the component is identical there can be no current flow through the component. The component under test is then effectively isolated from the rest of the circuit.

The final step in ICT may be to apply power to the board and perform some basic functional testing, programming, etc. The goal is to perform as much as possible at this step before adding additional cost by assembling the PCB into a housing before final functional testing.

In-circuit testing has largely been replaced by automated optical inspection. An image of a known good board is compared to an image of the board under test. Differences between the two images are easily detected. With this method solder balls (shorts), missing components, reversed components, and most wrong components (provided they have markings) can be detected much faster.

Answer (score 2):

These are test points. Test points on modern PCBs are used with a machine called flying probe. A robotic arm makes contact with each test point during testing. The flying probe can power the PCB, inject signals, and sample the outputs.

[image: flying probe]

[source](https://www.note-uk.co.uk/uk-manufacturing/flying-probe-test/)

They are also used for programming the ICs. You can even do stuff like programming the ICs with special testing programs and then re-programming them with the actual production program. That’s why you’ll see test points on production PCBs.